# Get current week Sunday date from todays date using Google Sheets/Excel

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I need to get the Current Sunday date from todays date.

I have tried this but it gives previous week Sunday, expected date is `11 Oct 2020` (today is `13 Oct 2020`)

Here are Today Vs Expected Values

```
Formula that uses this Date -> Result
10 Oct ->  04 Oct
11 Oct  -> 11 Oct
12 Oct  -> 11 Oct
13 Oct  -> 11 Oct
14 Oct  -> 11 Oct
15 Oct  -> 11 Oct
16 Oct  -> 11 Oct
17 Oct  -> 11 Oct
18 Oct  -> 18 Oct
19 Oct  -> 18 Oct

    =TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY()) - 1) - 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With dates in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1-(WEEKDAY(A1)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried this but it gives previous week Sunday, expected date is
> 11 Oct 2020 (today is 13 Oct 2020)

You don't need `-7`. Simply try:

`=TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY()) - 1)`

and as the other answer suggests, replace `Today()` with the desired dates.